# mysql - select field from highest ID row

Tags: mysql

This would be the schema simplified:

```
    CREATE TABLE Participant
    (`id` int, `Name` varchar(7))
;
    CREATE TABLE Term
    (`id` int, `participant_id` int, `start_date` date, `end_date` date)
;
INSERT INTO Participant
    (`id`, `Name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Mike'),
    (2, 'John'),
    (3, 'Peter')
;    
    INSERT INTO Term
    (`id`, `participant_id`,`start_date`, `end_date`)
VALUES
    (1, '1', '2016-10-04', '2016-12-04'),
    (2, '1', '2016-05-04', '2016-07-04'),
    (3, '1', '2016-03-04', '2016-05-04')
```

Then my query would be like this

```
Select Participant.name, Term.id, Term.start_date, Term.end_date

from  Term
inner join Participant where Term.participant_id = Participant.id;
```

Only I need to add a field that is difference between the lowest ID term start_date and the highest ID term end_date, for one participant.

And then it should look like:

```
Name Term.ID Term.Start_date Term.End_date Difference(days)*

Mike 1         2016-10-04    2016-12-04    154
Mike 2         2016-05-04    2016-07-04    154
Mike 3         2016-03-04    2016-05-04    154
```

*It is the difference between the lowest ID term start_date and the highest ID term end_date from one participant. And it would be displayed the same every time for each participant

So it would be the difference from 2016-10-04(ID 1 start_date) to 2016-05-04(ID 3 end_date). So it would be from october to may. That would make 154 days difference, or -154 because its going backwards.

I just cant figure out what logic the logic is. How to figure out inside the query which is the highest and lowest ID term within that participant terms.

This is where I have gone so far:

```
    SELECT 
            participant.user_id, 
            participant.name, 
            term.term_id,
            term.start_date, 
            term.end_date

       /*DATEDIFF(MAX(term.pt_prgm_term_insur_start_date),MIN(term.pt_prgm_term_insur_end_date)) x */

FROM pt participant
    JOIN prgm_term term on participant.user_id = term.user_id
```

And this is the result from it:

```
user_id   user_name     term_id start_date  end_date     difference
29415     Yi            143770  2004-12-15  2005-06-13     563
29415     Yi            143771  2005-06-14  2005-12-17     563
29417     Guillermo     143772  2004-11-08  2005-07-07     ?
29418     Raul          143773  2004-11-08  2005-07-07     ?
29419     Volker        143774  2005-01-03  2005-08-01     ?
29420     Tomas         143775  2004-11-15  2006-06-13     ?
29415     Yi            143776  2005-12-18  2006-06-30     563
29422     Hulda         143777  2004-11-15  2006-06-13     ?
29424     Jan           143778  2004-11-15  2005-03-16     ?
29425     Catherine     143779  2004-12-01  2006-07-01     ?
```

So if I take Yi as an example. Yi has 3 terms withe the ID's 143770,143771 and 143776. So I would have to capture the start_date from 143770(2004-12-15) and the end date from the 143776(2006-06-30), calculate the days difference and show it in the "difference" column for all Yi's terms. The difference would be 563 days.

Using @strawberry hint I got to this

```
user_id   user_name     term_id     start_date  end_date     difference
1         Peter             155857  2003-10-01  2004-04-30  -212
16        Mika              155861  1997-11-01  1998-11-30  -394
17        Masayuki          155862  1997-11-01  1997-11-30  -29
18        Kazuko            155863  1997-11-01  1997-11-30  -29
418       Tobias            155915  1997-03-01  1997-09-30  -213
419       Dirk              155916  1997-03-01  1997-09-30  -213
420       Markus            155917  1998-03-01  1997-09-30   152
421       Ruth              155918  1997-03-01  1997-09-30  -213
422       Anne-Kathrin      155919  1997-03-01  1997-09-30  -213
423       Tobias            155920  1997-03-01  1997-09-30  -213
```

by using this query

```
SELECT 
        participant.user_id, 
        participant.name, 
        term.term_id,
        term.start_date, 
        term.end_date,
        DATEDIFF(MIN(term.start_date),MAX(term.end_date)) x

FROM pt participant
JOIN pt_prgm_term term on participant.user_id = term.user_id 

group by user_id
```

The difference is working perfectly, only its showing one row for each participant(because of the group by) while I need to show all terms and reproduce the difference for each term. If I group by term_id, then the difference is calculated within each term and not the way it was before(between highest and lowest Id terms)

this is what it should be

```
 user_id   user_name     term_id     start_date  end_date     difference
    1         Peter             155857  2003-10-01  2004-04-30  -212
    1         Peter             155861  1997-11-01  1998-11-30  -212
    17        Masayuki          155862  1997-11-01  1997-11-30  -29
    18        Kazuko            155863  1997-11-01  1997-11-30  -29
    418       Rafael            155915  1997-03-01  1997-09-30  -220
    419       Dirk              155916  1997-03-01  1997-09-30  -210
    420       Markus            155917  1998-03-01  1997-09-30  -213
    420       Markus            155918  1997-03-01  1997-09-30  -213
    420       Markus            155919  1997-03-01  1997-09-30  -213
    423       Tobias            155920  1997-03-01  1997-09-30  -229
```

Peter and Markus would be the examples

Comment: @Strawberry made the changes, is that what you meant?

Comment: thanks for that! here it is

Comment: It comes from Mike's Terms. It is the difference between Mike's first term(lowest ID) start_date and Mike's last term(Highest ID) end_date. Difference in days.

Comment: Its actually from 2016-10-04(ID 1 start_date) to 2016-05-04(ID 3 end_date). So it would be from october to may. That would make 154 days difference, or -154 because its going backwards.

Comment: But I guess it would be the same logic as the dates you thought. I just cant figure out what logic is that. How to figure out inside the query which is the highest and lowest ID term within that participant terms.

Comment: It's still a little unclear. I think it would useful to provide a more representative data set, and a corresponding desired result set.

Comment: updated again with the results i want

Comment: The data set does not match the result set.

Comment: it is an example. and its different because the first one is grouping by user and the second not, so one user can appear multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found an answer to this. Many thanks to @Strawberry for showing me the way.

I had to create a subquery inside my select statement in order to get the correct information.

The final query is this:

```
SELECT 
        participant.user_id as participant_ID, 
        participant.name, 
        term.term_id,
        term.start_date, 
        term.end_date,

(select 

        DATEDIFF(MIN(term.start_date),MAX(term.end_date))

        from
        pt participant
        join
        pt_prgm_term term on participant.user_id = term.user_id 

        WHERE participant.user_id = participant_ID
        GROUP BY participant.user_id ) as difference


FROM pt participant
JOIN pt_prgm_term term on participant.user_id = term.user_id
```

Comment: I don't think this query can return anything other than a syntax error.

Comment: You should look into subqueries. Check this out:
https://blog.rjmetrics.com/2008/10/28/correlated-subqueries-in-mysql/
It is working for me :)

Comment: I really don't need to. I'm quite good at MySQL, and know a syntax error when I see one.

Comment: and what would that be?

Comment: A missing JOIN keyword

Comment: Well spotted! I had to change some of the names and must have missed that. Anyway, the idea is there. You are quite good at being arrogant too. But really, thank you for showing me the way.

Comment: And you're quite good at being patronising. But really, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MAX(start_date),MIN(end_date)) x FROM term;
```

Comment: That would select the max and min dates within all terms, no? I need to show all terms from all participants, but in each row(one term) there would be a column for that difference. Only that difference is considering only the terms with the same user_id

Comment: Well, select the participant and the term and group by those - it helps if you provide properly representative data.

Comment: @rafaelbonametti Come on. Have a guess, based on the information provided so far.

Comment: just dont understand why when I insert the datediff it only gives me one result back

Comment: @rafaelbonametti Did you group by anything?

Comment: Great. It works! Sorry if this was silly, its my first time using sql. But still, its calculating the difference between each term, not between different terms

Comment: Is there a way I can expand the grouped participants so I can show all terms?